# PC freezes after fresh install

Tags: fedora, arch-linux, elementary-os, freeze

I have migrated yesterday from Windows to Linux. At first, I installed ElementaryOS. After ~2mins of browsing web and setting things up, the PC froze; I had to restart it. It happened every time I booted it up.
I then reinstalled to Fedora, same thing. Arch Linux, same thing (not in console, only after setting up the desktop environment). 
So I decided I would run MemTest86+ to see if there is something wrong with the memory. After 1 hour and few minutes, MemTest86+ froze too; it didn't work, I couldn't do anything, but the "+" sign in the upper left corner kept blinking, which was weird.

Would you have any suggestions on what could be the cause of this?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 I haven't. How should I do that when I can't even fire up OS? Or open up the case and check manually?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 ok, i just tried it. Everything was well within the range when it froze (cpu at around 35C). I also tried plugging it another keyboard/mouse, but they just started blinking but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from my own bad experiance, the reason might be the driver for the graphics card.

I would suggest that you try to change the drives for the GPU, especially if it is Nvidia GPU.

For me the proprietary Nvidia driver solved the similar issue.